# iOS cocos2d low frame rate on device

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, frame-rate

I'm developing a cocos2d game (using iOS 6 SDK and cocos2d 2.0rc2) and am having issues with a lower frame rate on the device. This causes issues with collision detection because most of it deals with the user drawing a line. The lower frame rate causes the points to be drawn farther apart and the object can go through the line because it never hits the points. The frame rate issue seems to happen most when I get a notification. Instead of the frame rate returning to normal when the notification disappears, it stays low and never returns to 60fps. Any ideas what might be causing this or a solution to handle the lines better with a lower fps?

Here is the drawing code, let me know if you want to see anything else.

```
-(void) draw {
    glLineWidth(lineScale);

for (int i = 0; i < touchesArray.count; i += 2) {
    CGPoint start = CGPointFromString([touchesArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    CGPoint end = CGPointFromString([touchesArray objectAtIndex:i + 1]);

    ccDrawLine(start, end);
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain how you show the notification and how it gets off screen. I mean..you use move ,fade, scale ..or what?

Comment: Check for leaks and/or use Time Profiler, it will help you out a lot

Comment: I'm talking about push notifications, like text messages